How to fix Form Data via XHR returns 400 Bad Request
This is my code, quite simple. just a POST request to my api endpoint with FormData.
but for some unknown reason the api says the data is a bad request. i tested my api via curl and it works fine.
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file); // file is a File object from an file input element
formData.append("extension", extension); // just text
formData.append("api_key", api_key); // just text
let url = "http://example.com/my/api/url/here";
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", url);
request.responseType = "json";
request.send(formData);

in chrome's dev tools, the payload tab looks like this, it correctly labels it as FormData
------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="video_file.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="extension"

video_file.mp4
------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_key"

e024d3-d2c3ec-97ea45-025ffe-910e53
------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP--

The request headers are these.
POST /my/api/url/here HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,as;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52751209
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP
Host: test-api.clipdrop.io
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"

Here is the curl (extracted via the dev tools) which returns a succesful response.
curl 'http://example.com/my/api/url/here' ^
  -H "Accept: */*" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,as;q=0.8" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP" ^
  -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" ^
  -H "Referer: http://localhost:3000/" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H ^"sec-ch-ua: ^\^"Not/A)Brand^\^";v=^\^"8^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"126^\^", ^\^"Google Chrome^\^";v=^\^"126^\^"^" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" ^
  -H ^"sec-ch-ua-platform: ^\^"Windows^\^"^" ^
  --data-raw ^"------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"file^\^"; filename=^\^"video_file.mp4^\^"^

Content-Type: video/mp4^

^

^

------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"extension^\^"^

^

video_file.mp4^

------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP^

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=^\^"api_key^\^"^

^

e024d3-d2c3ec-97ea45-025ffe-910e53^

------WebKitFormBoundaryxVfw6PrIESuvhgwP--^

^"

any ideas what the issue is?

Can't see any reason for the XMLHttpRequest giving a 400 and the curl not. Can you put your api server in trace level logging and see why the 400 is being generated?

Implement request.onerror and request.onload for debugging. Something like
request.onerror = function() {
    console.error(request.response);
};

request.onload = function() {
    console.log(request.response);
};

And ensure that your backend server is configured to handle CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) properly.
